# ParseDate on Fetch Before Data is Stored in Results

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am fetching form items from a list on SharePoint, then posting them to a printable HTML page that is also sortable and only shows items based off the date that they were submitted. With that in mind, SharePoint/fetch is returning an ISOString of (2021-01-18T06:00:00Z). I created another post a few days ago where I was using an AJAX and a solution was created for that, but when I implemented it into the fetch, nothing happens and the WeekOf variable is still stored as (2021-01-18T06:00:00Z).

The solution for the AJAX was: Here is the link to the **[POST](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/289277/parsedate-of-a-sharepoint-list-variable-pulled-through-ajax-call)**

```
for (var idx = 0; idx <data.d.results.length; idx++) {
            // turn the ISO string into a Date
            var weekOfDate = new Date(data.d.results[idx].WeekOf);
            // reformat the string and store it back to the "WeekOf"
            // property you are trying to replace
            data.d.results[idx].WeekOf = weekOfDate.toLocaleDateString();
        }
```

Here is my new fetch: (this is just the top part of my JS, if more is needed please let me know)

```
function loadData(url) {
    url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('WeeklyReport')/items?$select=DeliverablesSubmitted,MajorTasks,PersonnelActions,SupportRequest,ResourceRequest,Team,Training,Upcoming,WeekOf,TravelODC";
    return fetch(url, { headers: { accept: "application/json; odata=verbose" } }) // make request
      .then((r) => {
        if (!r.ok) throw new Error("Failed: " + url);  // Check for errors
        return r.json();  // parse JSON
      })
      .then((data) => data.d.results);
  }
  loadData()
    .then((results) => {
        const data = results;
        var listContent = [];
      
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
         listContent += '<li data-weekOf="'+data[i].WeekOf+'">';
         listContent += '<h2>' + data[i].Team  +'</h2>';
         listContent += '<h4> Tasks </h4>';
         if(data[i].MajorTasks !== null){
            listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].MajorTasks + '</ul>';
         }else{
              listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
         }
         listContent += '<h4> Deliverables Submitted</h4>';
                 if(data[i].Deliverables !== null){
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Deliverables + '</ul>';
         }else{
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
         }
```

Comment: More of your JS is needed.  Also, you don’t appear to be setting a limit on the number of items returned.

Comment: check out this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829569/parsing-iso-8601-date-in-javascript/4829642#4829642

Comment: @A.k.A.Fritz that is because there is no limit on the number of items coming in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This by design.SharePoint stores Time information in Universal Time Code format (UTC),If you want to display in a different format, you can only modify the time format after reading.